# ODP pass array of integers

Tags: c#, oracle

This problem is driving me crazy. I am trying to pass an array of integers to `ORACLE` function, but with no success.

I have a table `scada_stops_header` with columns:

```
 1. ST_EVENTGROUPID NUMBER(15,0) 
 2. ST_CATEG        NUMBER(6,0)
 3. ST_SUBCATEG     NUMBER(6,0)
```

Here is the package code:

```
create or replace package scada as
....
  type stopid_record is record(stop_id scada_stops_header.st_eventgroupid%type);
  type stopid_table is table of stopid_record INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
....

  function stops_set(fids_table in stopid_table,
                 fcateg     in scada_stops_header.st_categ%type,
                 fsubcateg  in scada_stops_header.st_subcateg%type,
                 ferrmsg    out nvarchar2) return number;
```

And here is the `C#` code:

```
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("scada.stops_set", con))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    var pResult = new OracleParameter("return", OracleDbType.Int32);
    pResult.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

    var pIDs = new OracleParameter("fids_table", OracleDbType.Decimal);
    pIDs.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    pIDs.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
    pIDs.Value = stops.Stops;

    var pCategory = new OracleParameter("fcateg", OracleDbType.Int32);
    pCategory.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    pCategory.Value = stops.TypeID;

    var pSubcategory = new OracleParameter("fsubcateg", OracleDbType.Int32);
    pSubcategory.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    pSubcategory.Value = stops.SubtypeID;

    var pError = new OracleParameter("ferrmsg", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, 500);
    pError.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(pIDs);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(pCategory);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(pSubcategory);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(pError);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(pResult);

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I am getting exception:

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x00001996):
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 15: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of
>   arguments in call to 'STOPS_SET' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL:
>   Statement ignored

I have tried passing `Int32`, `Int64`, `Decimal`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems I can not use complex types as a table parameter. I have changed type definition to:

```
type stopid_table is table of 
   scada_stops_header.st_eventgroupid%type INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

Now it works.